# Stack corruption in Ada C binding to OpenGL function

Tags: c, opengl, binding, sdl, ada

I'm using SDL to retrieve the address of the function. That much seems to be working, since I'm using the same subprogram that's working for all my other function calls.

Here are all the relevant code snippits in the spec:

```
type GLenum is new Uint32;

subtype glTexImage2D_Target is GLenum with Static_Predicate => glTexImage2D_Target in GL_TEXTURE_2D | GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE | GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE;
subtype glTexImage2D_Dtype is GLenum with Static_Predicate => glTexImage2D_Dtype in GL_BYTE | GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
subtype glTexImage2D_InternalFormat is GLenum with Static_Predicate => glTexImage2D_InternalFormat in GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT | GL_DEPTH_STENCIL | GL_RED | GL_RG | GL_RGB | GL_RGBA;
subtype glTexImage2D_Format is GLenum with Static_Predicate => glTexImage2D_Format in GL_RED | GL_RG | GL_RGB | GL_BGR | GL_RGBA | GL_BGRA | GL_RED_INTEGER | GL_RG_INTEGER | GL_RGB_INTEGER | GL_BGR_INTEGER | GL_RGBA_INTEGER | GL_BGRA_INTEGER | GL_STENCIL_INDEX | GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT | GL_DEPTH_STENCIL;

procedure glTexImage2D(target : glTexImage2D_Target; level : Integer; internalFormat : glTexImage2D_InternalFormat; width : Integer; height : Integer; format : glTexImage2D_Format; dtype : glTexImage2D_Dtype; pixels : System.Address) with Pre => (target /= GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE and target /= GL_PROXY_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE) or Level = 0;

procedure Set_OpenGL_Subprogram_Address(Addr : in out System.Address; Name : String);

glTexImage2D_C_Address : System.Address := System.Null_Address;

Could_Not_Load_OpenGL_Subprogram : exception;
```

And here are the relevant snippits in the body:

```
procedure glTexImage2D(target : glTexImage2D_Target; level : Integer; internalFormat : glTexImage2D_InternalFormat; width : Integer; height : Integer; format : glTexImage2D_Format; dtype : glTexImage2D_Dtype; pixels : System.Address) is
begin
    Set_OpenGL_Subprogram_Address(glTexImage2D_C_Address, "glTexImage2D");
    declare
        procedure glTexImage2D_C(target : GLenum; level : GLint; internalFormat : GLint; width : GLsizei; height : GLsizei; border : GLint; format : GLenum; dtype : GLenum; data : System.Address)
        with Import, Convention => Stdcall, Address => glTexImage2D_C_Address;
    begin
        glTexImage2D_C(GLenum(target), GLint(level), GLint(internalFormat), GLsizei(width), GLsizei(height), GLint'(0), GLenum(format), GLenum(dtype), pixels);
    end;
end glTexImage2D;

--This seems to work... but here it is just in case.
procedure Set_OpenGL_Subprogram_Address(Addr : in out System.Address; Name : String) is
begin
    if Addr = System.Null_Address then
        Addr := SDL_GL_GetProcAddress(Value(New_String(Name)));
        if Addr = System.Null_Address then
            raise Could_Not_Load_OpenGL_Subprogram with Name;
        end if;
    end if;
end Set_OpenGL_Subprogram_Address;
```

Finally, the pixels I'm passing in is an address indicating an object of type:

```
type Uc_Array is array(Integer range <>) of aliased Interfaces.C.unsigned_char;
```

The stack is being corrupted on the call to glTexImage2D_C. I discovered this by using gdb:

[image]

Here you can see the parameters I'm passing as well; target 3553, level 0, internalformat 6408, width 63, height 63, format 6408, dtype 5121, non-zero pixels address. The subprogram address is being set to a non-zero value. But after the call to glTexImage2D_C, the value of $sp (the stack pointer) has increased by 16#24#.

I've tried adjusting the height and width I pass to glTexImage2D_C, both to 10 and both to 1000, just to see if giving it more (or less) buffer prevents stack corruption, but in every case, the stack pointer is different before and after the procedure call.

I'm hoping this is a simple matter of an incorrect datatype or something... Here's the prototype of [glTexImage2D](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) on the OpenGL side:

```
void glTexImage2D(  GLenum target,
    GLint level,
    GLint internalformat,
    GLsizei width,
    GLsizei height,
    GLint border,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    const void * data);
```

*(As a final note, I do intend to clean up the awkward lazy loading tactic you see above, if I can ever get this to actually work. For now I'm leaving it this way so I can eliminate the chance of trying to call a function that hasn't been loaded yet, while I'm still trying to debug the call itself. The tactic of using a nested procedure declared inside a declare...begin...end block is working for other OpenGL functions.)*

Comment: Is it a GL binding which is part of a SDL binding?

Comment: 1. what is your question?
2. Why Convention => Stdcall? Have you tried Convention => C?
3. Is this Windows?

Comment: Short answer, no. The official SDL Ada binding isn't quite comprehensive. The only piece of this binding above is SDL_GL_GetProcAddress. I am using this to load OpenGL functions, but I still have to write the bindings myself.

Comment: 1. How do I make it stop corrupting the stack? 2. Yes, I've tried both. Neither solves the issue. OpenGL functions are declared APIENTRY, so Stdcall is the convention I've been working with as default. 3. Yes, this is Windows.

Comment: Did you try reusing an existing GL binding, like https://globe3d.sourceforge.io/ or https://flyx.github.io/OpenGLAda/ ? Actually it is not clear what your problem is: a issue with your GL binding itself, or something in a bridge between SDL and GL?

Comment: The stack pointer has increased by exactly the number of bytes being passed as arguments, which to me suggests it needs to be called with C convention, not stdcall.

Comment: This is an increase of hex 24, while the parameters being passed should come to 32 bytes (counting the void* as 8 since it's a 64-bit machine), which is hex 20. Nonetheless, I tried changing back to C convention and still see the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the call of `glTexImage2D` in Ada, ensure that the value (type Uc_Array) that you are passing into the `pixels` parameter are called as `X(X'First)'Address`. (This should be the same as `X'Address`)

Secondly, ensure your `format` and `dtype` parameters are correct -- I would recommend making a small testbed: looking up the actual values, hard-coding them, then calling the imported (OpenGL) function, then having a working interop "complexify" it out into the SDL.

When dealing with a new interop project, it almost is always more fruitful to ensure the interoperationality is working as expected *before* jumping in. (That is, don't assume that it's going to "just work".)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are on Windows, thus you need to check that Stdcall convention is appropriate. As far as I remember, regular OpenGL library use C convention.